# Estimate $\sigma$ from a data given the total frequency and the sum of squares of frequencies.

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

In a frequency table with classes of equal width,$N_1$ is the total frequency and $N_2$ is the sum of squares of the frequencies. Assuming the distribution to be approximately normal with mean $0$, I'm asked to suggest a quick estimate of the standard deviation $\sigma$ in terms of $N_1$ and $N_2$.

> My approach: I've first deduced the formula involving the sum of the
>   square of the density of an $N(\mu,\sigma)$ variate (it doesn't depend
>   on $\mu$) :
>
> $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[f(x)]^2\,\mathrm{dx}=\dfrac{1}{2\sigma\sqrt{\pi}}\tag*{}$
>
> Now, $\displaystyle\sum_{i}\dfrac{f(x)}{N_1}=1$. Then
>   $\displaystyle\sum_{i}\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{N_1}\right)^2=\dfrac{N_2}{N_1^2}.$
>
> I think $\displaystyle\sum_{i}\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{N_1}\right)^2\cdot h$
>   resembles to
>   $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[f(x)]^2\,\mathrm{dx}=\dfrac{1}{2\sigma\sqrt{\pi}}$ where $h=$ class width.
>
> So,
>   $h\cdot\dfrac{N_2}{N_1^2}=\dfrac{1}{2\sigma\sqrt{\pi}}\implies\sigma=\dfrac{2h\sqrt{\pi}N_2}{N_1^2}.$
>
> I'm confused about the answer, so please help me and suggest edits if
>   its wrong.

Comment: How do you define $f$? Frequency/frequency density/probability density function?

Comment: $f$=probability density function, $f_i=$frequency of the $i$th class interval.

Comment: Then use $f_i$.

Comment: Where to use $f_i$?

Comment: In place of $f(x)$ where you write $\sum_i f(x)/N_1=1$, etc.

Comment: I'm confused by which I can replace $\int f(x)\,dx$- by $\sum \frac{f_i}{N_1}$ or by $\sum \frac{f_i}{N_1}h$?